# How to get MenuItem position in the listener using the new NavigationView

Tags: android, navigationview

The topic says it all. How should I go about retrieving the item position on the onClick listener using NavigationView? Also, why is there no getHeader method? Lastly I am doing everything programmatically, but the header is still clickable. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You can set listener using `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener()` and implementing `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` for receiving item click

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can get position using this trick

```
final List<MenuItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
Menu menu;

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);.
menu = navigationView.getMenu();

for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++){
    items.add(menu.getItem(i));
}

navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
        // update highlighted item in the navigation menu
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        int position = items.indexOf(menuItem);

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with the listener, but I don't understand why they don't implement a getPosition() method. What is the intended use case?

Comment: If menuitem obj is there you can pass that as parameter to any method to perform anything...

Comment: Could you be more specific? Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I found a simple solution. You can assign an order using Menu's [`add(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method. Then you can retrieve the order using MenuItems's [`getOrder(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getOrder%28%29) method. If you are using xml, you can use `android:orderInCategory="..."`.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);.
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

for(int i=0; i < menu.size(); i++){
    items.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, i, menu.getItem(i));
}

navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
        // update highlighted item in the navigation menu
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        int position=items.getOrder();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't know if this is the correct way to do it, but it worked, so thanks (Y)

Comment: I consider the best option which you say about switch (item.getOrder()) and put android:orderInCategory="..." in the XML. Thank you very much.

Comment: This seems to be the best way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can just take its *order* if you specify the "android:orderInCategory" attribute for menu items:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:title="@string/news" />
    <item
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/search" />
</menu>
```

```kotlin
val navigationView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.navigation)

navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
    val menuItemOrder = menuItem.order

    true
}
```

Or, use this in case you don't want to specify orders by hand:

```kotlin
val navigationView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.navigation)

navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
    val menuItemIndex = bottomNavigation.menu.children.indexOf(menuItem)

    true
}
```

Comment: This answer is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `menu_drawer.xml`, you just have to add an `id` in the items like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_top_stories"
    android:title="@string/txt.menu.item1"
/>
```

With this you just have to test on `menuItm.getId()`:

```
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
        // update highlighted item in the navigation menu
        menuItem.setChecked(true);

        switch(menuItem.getId()){
           case R.id.txt_menu_item1 : //do what you want to do;
           break;
           case R.id.txt_menu_item2 : // etc,
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

If you are using dynamic menu, just use this method to add an item to you navigation drawer:

```
NavigationView.getMenu().add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title)
```

And then test by the order:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
        // update highlighted item in the navigation menu
        menuItem.setChecked(true);

        switch(menuItem.getOrder()){
           case 0 : //do what you want to do;
           break;
           case 1 : // etc,
           default : //do whatever you want ;
        }
       return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i use

first test whit this..

```
Log.d(TAG, navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).isChecked());
Log.d(TAG, navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).isChecked());
Log.d(TAG, navigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).isChecked());
```

next this...

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        if(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).isChecked()) {
            cerrarSesion();
        }else {
            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
            seleccionarItem(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy, and most clean (in my opinion) way:

```
private int getBottomNavigationItemPosition(@MenuRes int itemId) {
    final Menu bottomNavigationMenu = mBottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    final int menuItemCount = bottomNavigationMenu.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < menuItemCount; i++) {
        if (bottomNavigationMenu.getItem(i).getItemId() == itemId) return i;
    }
    return -1; // the item with itemId was not found in Menu
}
```