# Make current active item in Navigation changed Color

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to change the background color of my `Navigation` drawer menu. When an item is `pressed` it changes to red and what I wanted to achieve is it stays red after clicking because it is the current active item in the `Navigation` and even the drawer is closed.

I created a `drawable` xml where I set the `background` of the item  (item_bg.xml) here's my code

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/brickred" />
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/brickred" />
<item android:state_active="true" android:drawable="@color/brickred" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/brickred" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/brickred" />
</selector>
```

and calls it to my `navigation_activity.xml` like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer"
    android:background="@color/tableHeader"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/item_bg"/>

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? thank you.

---

Here's my `NavigationActivity` looks like:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
  @Override
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Intent goToSreen;

    if (id == R.id.nav_dashboard) {
        goToSreen = new Intent(NavigationActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(goToSreen);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_dashboard);
    }
```

but it still goes back to its original color after the `drawer` is closed.

Comment: Try: In your style: `<style name="YourStyleNameFor.NavigationDrawer" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/your_highlight_color</item>
</style>` and include the style in `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
` !!!  `    app:theme="@style/YourThemeNameFor.NavigationDrawer"
`

Comment: Similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956978/navigationviewchange-color-of-selected-item)

Answer (score 3):

I tried this

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31233478/4247543)

Comment: How can I get the position of it when selected? Also i tried it only works in onCreate is there a way where I can use it on onNavigationItemSelected ?

Comment: pass the postion as parameter to getItem()

Comment: navigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);

Comment: for postion check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/31872096/4247543

Comment: i tried that i get the position correctly but it goes back to its original color after the drawer is closed

Comment: try navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_item)

Comment: where should I put it? i tried to put it on my `onNavigationItemSelected` but it still goes back to its original color. I updated my question and added my code on my `NavigationActivity`. Kindly please check it. Thank you.

Comment: see if u missed to add this https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiTn5PgiZfUAhVFtY8KHZL8BgQQygQIRDAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Ftopics%2Fui%2Fmenus.html%23checkable&usg=AFQjCNG4q-8pJUzY31db9nkBd5EgHp-RgQ

Comment: i have `<group android:checkableBehavior="single">`